# Doctrine fails to create object from record having special character less than or greater than < , >

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using mysql database and one of the column of my table has value as `<, >` symbols.

I have set CHARSET *UTF8* in doctrine configuration,

When I print this using

`\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($result);`

It prints incomplete object. It prints only values till the field having symbol `<, >`. Other fields are not printed and it gives 500 error. There is no specific error or exception. Object just does't have other fields.

I tried executing query from log, it works fine, it fetches all columns. But doctrine is failing to create complete object.

The query is simple as below,

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery("SELECT t FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Transaction t 
    WHERE t.id = :id");
$query->setParameters(array(
'id' => $id
));

if ($limit)
$query->setMaxResults($limit);

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: pls. write your query here. So we can provide some solution

Comment: I have added the query

Comment: Pls try this. `return $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();` **or** `return $query->getArrayResult();`

Comment: Did you look at the generated source? I assume the dump util doesn't escape HTML.

Comment: Yeah, dump util doesn't escape but its not just about dump util if I try to use result set, it gives error as object doesn't have remaining fields.